# Eyed3 Installation on Windows

Tags: python, windows

Can someone tell me (assuming I know nothing about anything) of how to install Eyed3 on a Windows system?

I've looked and looked, but I can't get it to work. I've renamed the `setup.py.in` and `__init__.py.in`, and tried running the setup.py file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add  details about how it doesn't work, without them it's difficult to help

Comment: it says the module is missing. how do i install it? someone told me to use cmd.

Comment: please post the exact output of `python setup.py.in install`

Comment: assume i'm an idiot, where am i typing this?

Comment: please put some effort in solving your problem, any google search "python windows tutorial" will tell you how. [Here  is a tutorial](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows)

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't sure what I was looking for. When I type `python setup.py.in install` into Run, a black box quickly appears and disappears..

Comment: Please read the article linked in my previous comment. I won't teach you how to use python not because I'm rude but because there are excellent resources on the net and you should take the time to learn.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I sorted it all out thanks to you. How do I recommend you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have followed [this tutorial](http://jwwishart.blogspot.fr/2011/01/python-eyed3-installation-on-windows.html) but don't know how to run python commands; check [this python doc](http://docs.python.org/faq/windows#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows) to learn how to call Python on Windows.

Comment: This helped me so much, but I can't up it since I don't have reputation.. I'm sorry

Comment: you can accept it at least (normally you can upvote answers on your own posts)